# Does importing random affect use of while loops?

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

This code snippet is from a python course being taught at a middle school. The file imports turtle and then random to allow for colors to be selected from a list while the square is being drawn. I tried changing the if to a while loop, and got an unexpected result. The loop continues after num = 0, printing 0 indefinitely. I tried removing the decrement outside of the call to 
sqspin(num-1) and doing the decrement on the line above like so: num = num -1
This change started creating random changes to the printed value of num for each successive loop after num reached 0 for the first time. I don't understand why while num > 0 doesn't terminate the loop when num = 0, or where those random values for num are coming from. Any clues? 
I'm running 3.4.3, but the school is using 2.7.

```
from turtle import *
from random import *

shape("turtle")
st()

def sq():
    fd(100)
    rt(90)
    fd(100)
    rt(90)
    fd(100)
    rt(90)
    fd(100)
    rt(90)

colors = ['red', 'green', 'orange', 'blue', 'yellow']

def  pickcolor():
    return choice(colors)

def sqspin(num):
    print(num)
    if num > 0:
        sq()
        rt(5)
        mycolor = pickcolor()
        pencolor(mycolor)
        sqspin(num-1)

sqspin(5)
```

Comment: Why did you add line numbers?

Comment: Because you never change `num`! You pass `num - 1` in a recursive call, but that doesn't change `num` in the caller.

Comment: What is `sq`? Am I missing something?

Comment: You say "I tried changing..." twice. Did you try one change and then the other, exclusively? Or did you try both changes at the same time? Can you share the exact code that you ended up with, rather than the code you started with?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
Give us a particular problem, the output you got, the output you expected, and the code needed to reproduce it.  Your current code doesn't run.

Comment: DONT put code in the comments. There is no way to make it legible. Edit the question instead

Comment: The order of the numbers after 0 is *not* random. Your while-loops are just finishing in stack-order.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Changed the original post.

Comment: Cargo cult programming will not help you to learn the class's material before the students do. It will be much more effective to consult with your professor or use your school's tutoring center, as this site is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Not asking for tutoring. Just confused as to why the while loop is not terminating when the condition becomes false, but the if statement works. The professor who designed the course is on vacation, as am I. I was just trying to understand a confusing result. And I'm sorry, but I do not understand your reference to Cargo cult programming. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you suggest, but just changing the `if` to a `while` isn't sufficient.  Where you're getting confused is with the difference between *recursion* and *iteration*.  The algorithm is currently recursive, to make it iterative we can:

```
def sqspin(num):
    while num > 0:
        print(num)
        sq()
        rt(5)
        pencolor(pickcolor())
        num -= 1
```

Note that in addition to the `if` becoming a `while`, we remove the recursive call to `sqspin()` and decrement `num` within the loop instead of within the recursive call parameters.  (And move `print(num)` into the loop so that it can perform it's original purpose.)

Comment: Thank you for your constructive response.. The recursive call was creating an issue I hadn't considered when I changed to a while loop. I now have a better understanding of the difference in usage of if and while.